# Qual a diferença entre ironia e sarcasmo?

Tags: significado, figura-de-estilo

De forma simples, qual a diferença e como definir o que é ironia e o que é sarcasmo?

Gostaria de ver uma frase num determinado contexto e saber se aquilo é sarcasmo ou ironia.

Comment: Você tá tirando onda? :P . . . Sarcasmo à parte, pode expandir um pouco em qual a dúvida ou se tem algum exemplo onde mostre a confusão que pode haver?

Comment: @brasofilo. minha dúvida é mais geral. Gostaria de ver uma frase no determinado contexto e saber se aquilo é sarcasmo ou ironia.

Comment: Essa segunda frase sua, perfeita pra acrescentar na Pergunta :)

Comment: @brasofilo, fiz a edição. (:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- **Ironia**

  A ironia é uma forma de expressão literária ou uma figura de retórica que consiste em dizer o contrário daquilo que se pensa, deixando entender uma distância intencional entre aquilo que dizemos e aquilo que realmente pensamos. Na Literatura, a ironia é a arte de zombar de alguém ou de alguma coisa, com um ponto de vista a obter uma reação do leitor, ouvinte ou interlocutor.

  *Exemplos:*

  - A excelente dona Inácia era mestra na arte de judiar de crianças. (Monteiro Lobato)
  - Meu marido é um santo. Só me traiu três vezes!
- **Sarcasmo**

  É um tipo de ironia *mais amarga* e *provocatória*, transformando-se às vezes quase num *insulto*. A ironia é uma inversão do real significado de algo em determinado contexto, por exemplo, quando se diz o contrário do que se pensa. Apesar da função de criticar e censurar algo ou alguém, a ironia é uma reação mais moderada que o sarcasmo.

  Muitas vezes, um comentário sarcástico apresenta no seu conteúdo palavras cruéis que provocam uma reação ofensiva e mágoa em quem o recebe.

  *Exemplos:*

  - Senhora, tem um pouco de cara na sua maquiagem.
  - Espere um momento, estou tentando imaginar como você seria se tivesse cérebro.
  - O seu perfume é bom. Quanto tempo você esteve submerso nele?
  - Você precisa de um cirurgião plástico e não de um médico.

**fontes:**

- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironia
- http://www.significados.com.br/sarcasmo/

Comment: Era bom se tivesse exemplos.

Comment: Verdade, falta de atenção minha, já editei. Vou tentar adicionar mais exemplos posteriormente, estes por enquanto são das fontes

Comment: Bah, nunca havia pensado dessa forma. Parabéns pela resposta @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Obrigado! - Algumas pessoas sempre me dizem que sou sarcástico, mas agora sei que sou apenas irônico :) - Estou aliviado kk